# Audit trail for TTL delete operations in AWS DocumentDB?

Tags: aws-documentdb

AWS DocumentDB support automatic deletion of documents based on a TTL index according to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html#how-it-works.ttl-deletes

As far as I understand the audit functionality does not track changes on a document level: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/event-auditing.html

My question is if these deletes can be tracked somehow or if they are logged somewhere in AWS?

Right now the only way to solve this looks like implementing a change stream listener in application code and log deletes from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentDB currently does not support auditing DML operations such as TTL deletes. Implementing change stream listener to log deletes is the right solution for now.

-Meet